# Assembly Code for part-number P89LPC933935

Tags: c, assembly, embedded, 8051

I am working on translating assembly code to 'C', to which I came across a instruction which I am finding difficult to understand, here is the code

```
add  a,#0-3
jc   c_fail
```

I don't understand the line `add  a,#0-3`

Comment: Adding a number that's *almost* UINT_MAX will produce a carry on any input of 3 or larger; I think is what that's doing.  I assume that's an add-immediate into a register called `a`, with the value `0-3`, but I don't know 8051 specifically.

Comment: `ADD a, #immed` http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/is51/is51_add.htm

Comment: ... and http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/a51/a51_op_minus.htm

Answer (score 1):

`add  a,#0-3` is same as `add  a,#-3` that will adds `A` with `-3`. `-3` will be considered as `0xFD` in 8051 MCU. So, if `A` value be equal or greater than `3` (a >= 3), program will goes to the `c_fail` address due to carry flag.

Also, you can replace it with `subb a,#3`, if use from the `jnc` instead of `jc` in its next line.